# Query another model in instance method of a different model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It am trying to query a different **Model static method** in **instance method of another model**, and getting undefined, though i am using same outside the schema class and it's working.
For better overview, see sample code:

```
UserFormSchema.post('save', function (next) {
var form = this;
  Models.SubCategory.getById(form.subCategoryId).then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
  }).catch(function(err){
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
});


TypeError: Cannot read property 'SubCategory' of undefined
```

> Each Schema can define instance and static methods for its model.

Comment: Can you make a code snippet

Comment: try this.Models.getById

Comment: @Sam Tried but same

Comment: In your case 'this' is form please check with it

Comment: @Sam https://stackoverflow.com/a/38488773/1936186, i tried this and it's working

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38488773/1936186`

```
UserFormSchema.post('save', function (next) {
var form = this;
mongoose.model('SubCategory').getById(form.subCategoryId).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
   }).catch(function(err){
     return Promise.reject(err);
   });
});
```